# File for emergency card?

Tags: usa, greencard

I was curious if there was such a thing as filing or applying for a medical emergency card for a green card holder?

I recently had my wife petition to bring her mother here and she was granted I think they called it an I5 status which is mother of a US citizen daughter. She was given a green card immediately when entering the United States. She also recently got her SSN.

My wife keeps mentioning to me that I need to help my mother in law obtain an emergency medical card. However, I don't know if there is such a thing.  She is not a UN refugee I am responsible for her here on he US. So she does not get welfare or a bridge card or any benefits. However, my wife insists she can still apply for an emergency medical card. We are in the state of Michigan and cannot find much information about this.

Is she really eligible to apply for an emergency medical card?  If so how or where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They may be talking about Emergency Medicaid.

Medicaid is health insurance for low-income people. In most states, permanent residents have to wait 5 years after getting permanent residency to be eligible for regular Medicaid, though a few states offer it to permanent residents without a waiting period (I don't believe Michigan is one of them).

However, Emergency Medicaid is offered to all people (who meet the income requirements) regardless of status (including illegal immigrants and visitors), but it's only for emergency treatment (not regular doctor visits).

Comment: How do i apply for emergency medicaid?  My mother in law has no income, she is 55. We just need something in case of an emergency

Comment: @JonH, [the Michigan section of this document](http://library.niwap.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/pdf/PB-Man-Ch17.1-EmergencyMedicaid.pdf) suggests that you apply the same way as you would for regular Medicaid.

Comment: This answer and your help steered me in the right direction - thank you both!